# Gwt Hosted Mode Server Side Reloading

Tags: gwt, server-side, mode, hosted

Whenever I made code changes in GWT client side files I can just reload the browser or press "reload webserver" and the changes will be applied instantly. However, it doesn't work like that when I update my server side codes which means I have to stop the module and re-run it again which can take sometime. Is it suppose to happen like that? Is there anyway for the hosted mode to update instantly when I update server side code like client side?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The "reload webserver" button is what you're looking for: it "reloads" all the classes from your `war/WEB-INF` (`classes` and `lib`) and basically restarts your webapp.

If it doesn't work for you, then maybe it's because you don't compile your classes to your `war/WEB-INF/classes` and/or have them in the DevMode's classpath (you should then see warnings in the DevMode window saying the code wasn't loaded from the webapp but from the parent classloader).

Answer (score 0):

It is typical for server side code. Server code is run in Jetty and as far as I know it doesn't have option to reload automatically, though Tomcat has, so you could potentially run it in external server - there is such option.

One hint - don't stop and start, just use reload button (looks like refresh). It is much faster.

Comment: Jetty **does** have means to reload webapps automatically, it depends how you configure it (but that's the default behavior anyway).